# How do I calculate a checksum on all columns in a row using LINQ and Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The query I am trying to execute is similar to this:

```
var checksum = from i in db.Items
    where i.Id == id
    select SqlFunctions.Checksum("*");
```

However, this returns the checksum value of the string `"*"` rather than evaluating the wildcard. Is there a way to calculate the checksum of all the columns instead?

Update:

```
var checksum = db.Database.SqlQuery<int?>("SELECT CHECKSUM(*) FROM [Catalog].[Item] WHERE Id = @p0", id);
```

This gives me the result I want but seems dirty. Is there a way to do this without inline SQL?

Comment: did yout try : sqlfunctions.checksumaggregate(i.select(x => x.Id));

Comment: i has no select method. Also I need to calculate the checksum for all columns, not just Id.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate a checksum on all columns?

Comment: I need to test equality on a row on 2 identical tables in 2 separate databases.These are guaranteed to always guaranteed to have identical schemas. This was the simplest method I came up with.

Comment: Why not just join the two tables on all columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with the [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.  This Class allows for linq-to-entities code to include methods that are easily converted to Sql.

First of all in your current edit:  Using inline SQL is not 'dirty' and is totally fine in most (if not all) cases.  ORMs don't provide everything, especially if there isn't a good object-column mapping that exists.  However, since you're using entity framework you might as well get aquanted with the [`SqlFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static methods.

In this case there are a lot of overloads for performing a checksum, however they must all be of the same type.  Since you didn't post what types your columns or how many you have, I don't want to recommend the wrong overload in an example for you to use.

Here are your options:

**`SqlFunctions.Checksum()`:**

- `bool?`
- `char[]`
- `DateTime?`
- `DateTimeOffset?`
- `Decimal?`
- `double?`
- `Guid?`
- `TimeSpan?`
- `String`

All of the above have overloads to allow up to 3 parameters (of the same type).

**`SqlFunctions.AggregateChecksum()`:**

- `IEnumerable<int>`
- `IEnumerable<int?>`

If you take a look at the documentation for these functions you'll see that the parameters that you're passing are *VALUES*, not column names.  So you should be using them inside of a `Select()` clause.  This is why when you passed `"*"` to the operation it checksummed the string containing a single asterisk instead of all columns.  Also, keep in mind that these functions cannot be called directly, and must only be used within a Linq-To-Entities query.

Let's assume your columns named "ItemName" & "Description" are both strings, and you also want your id, which is an `int`:

```
var checksum = db.Items.Where(i => i.Id == id)
                       .Select(i => SqlFunctions.Checksum(i.Id.ToString(), i.ItemName, i.Description));
```

Unfortunately, as you see in the above example we had to cast our int to a string.  There are no overloads that allow for different typed parameters for computing a checksum, nor are there any options that allow for more than 3 parameters in the checksum function; however, as I mentioned above sometimes you need to do an inline SQL command and this is OK.

Comment: The columns are of different types, so these overloads wont be useful in this case. I thought the SQL seemed dirty because it is the only SQL in the project, and is currently located in my controller, since my entities were generated DB first. I suppose I could move it to a partial file in my models to get the bad taste out of my mouth.

Comment: @Jason If you really don't like having the SQL code in your project, you can always write a user-defined function or stored proc.  EF's support for these features isn't very powerful, but it does exist can then be used in a linq query.  However, remember that ER is an ORM, not a SQL replacement.  Sometimes you just need to write a sql query the old-fashioned way.